# Cannot read property X of undefined on call

Tags: javascript

So I have a class

```
class A {
    test() {
        return 1;
    }
    foo() {
        return this.baz(this.bar)
    }
    bar() {
        return this.baz(this.test);
    }
    baz(f){
        return f(); 
    }
}
```

And when I call the method `foo`

```
var a = new A();
a.foo();
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baz' of undefined
    at bar (<anonymous>:9:15)
    at A.baz (<anonymous>:12:10)
    at A.foo (<anonymous>:6:15)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

How appears that `this` becomes undefined after method f() is being called, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Ultimately it becomes something like: `var bar = a.bar; bar();` So, `this` will be undefined. Example 3 from the accepted answer: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429)

Answer (score 1):

By doing that:

```
return this.baz(this.bar)
```

you are just passing a function without specifying *what `this` its `this` refers to* (without its context). So ultimately, when you enter the `baz(f)` method, you get *a function* as a parameter, not *method* of the class `A`. So its `this` is undefined. To fix it, you have two options, first is to change the `foo()` method:

```
foo() {
    return this.baz(this.bar.bind(this))
}
```

and a second is to change the `baz(f)` method:

```
baz(f){
    return f.call(this); 
}
```

Both solutions will work in this case. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It was never defined.   You call function without context -  so does not have "this"

this.apply(f)  would bind it to object

Answer (score 0):

You can also use arrow function to solve this problem.

```js
class A {
    test =()=> {
        return 1;
    }
    foo=()=> {
        return this.baz(this.bar)
    }
    bar=()=> {
        return this.baz(this.test);
    }
    baz=(f)=>{
        return f(); 
    }
}

const a = new A()
console.log(a.foo())
```